# How to download image from 'save image' button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Trying to use python and selenium to download the image that is within the 'save image' button, I have the code to get rid of the cookies pop up but it won't let me click the save image button.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iaSs.png)

I tried the following code, mainly locating the button either through ID or Class name. But it just says the button is not clickable.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Edge()

mateo = "https://www.meteoblue.com/en/weather/14-days/ottawa_canada_6094817"

driver.get(mateo)

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "form-group").click()

#HREF link
link = "http://my.meteoblue.com/visimage/meteogram_14day_hd?download=1&look=KILOMETER_PER_HOUR%2CCELSIUS%2CMILLIMETER&apikey=5838a18e295d&temperature=C&windspeed=kmh&precipitationamount=mm&winddirection=3char&city=Ottawa&iso2=ca&lat=45.4112&lon=-75.6981&asl=71&tz=America%2FToronto&lang=en&ts=1686662836&sig=171b0d835cf2ae17a032512cf41b1244"

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "glyph download").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "chart_download")
download_link = button.get_attribute('href')
driver.get(download_link)
```